# Ignoring <image> tag?? SVG NOT LOADING IN PROCESSING

Tags: svg, processing

I have a project due for University that involves SVGs, however mine won't load. All I get is:

"Ignoring image tag.
The width and/or height is not readable in the svg tag of this file."

Please help? I'm trying to load an SVG that has colour in it. This is the code:

```
PShape m;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 720);
  m = loadShape("mountain.svg");
}

void draw(){
  background(102);
  shape(m, 110, 90, 50, 50);
}
```

And if you need the SVG or something, let me know.
Thanks

Comment: So does your SVG file have an `<image>` element that doesn't have `width` and `height` attributes?  That seems to be what the error is suggesting.

Comment: I don't know what that means. We were told to just use the code I'm using. I drew the original image, took it into Illustrator to vectorize it with image trace, took it into Photoshop to add colour then back to Illustrator to make it a SVG.

Comment: Add the mountain.svg to the question.

Comment: How would you like it added? I'm not a "high enough level" to add photos..

Comment: As markup, i.e. the source as text.

Comment: I am using my own created svg, and don't really know how to link it here?? I'm sorry, I'm kinda new to things involving svgs and processing...

Comment: SVG is just an XML file. Open it in a text editor and paste it as code, just like your other code.  Or upload it somewhere and post a link.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it.

just make sure that your artboard is bigger that your illustration. 
For instance, If you set the artboard to fit bounds, then processing would mostly likely give you this message.

Another thing that I realised is that if you're using illustrator 2015, your SVG file will be moved to the left of the processing screen, and sometimes outside of it.

A workaround would be to put your illustration towards the top right of the screen, then save as an SVG file.

OR, you could just download illustrator 2014, you can do that from the creative cloud app on your computer. Just remember to always leave plenty of space for your illustration in the illustrator dartboard before you save.

I hope that helps!